# Converting a javascript method's functionality to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, checksum

I have a javascript function that has functionality that I would like to convert to C#. I'm not sure how to properly translate this.

Can anyone help?

```
function validateSequenceNumber(val, num) {

   var seqNumber = ((parseFloat(num) + 0xCED9) * 0x8088405) & 0xFFFF
   var checksum = seqNumber.toString(16).toUpperCase()

   if (checksum != val.substring(11, 15)) {
     return false;
   }
    return true;
   }
```

Comment: do you not know C# syntax for this or what these hex values stands for?

Answer (score 3):

`parseFloat` becomes `float.Parse`, `seqNumber.toString(16)` becomes `string.Format("{0:x}", seqNumber).ToUpper();`

And note on substring parameters in C# are not start, end; rather start, length. So be careful. `function` becomes `bool` obviously. And I think that's it.

Comment: And you have to cast the `float` to `int` before `&`.

Comment: Yeah, mine was really straightforward, there maybe other errors too :) At least this could give an idea to the asker.

Answer (score 1):

The string functions used should also use the invariant culture, since the function doesn't appear to be used for text display.  Below is how the function might be converted:

```
 private static bool ValidateSequenceNumber(string val, string num) {
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo inv=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        int seqNumber = unchecked((((int)Double.Parse(num,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,inv) + 0xCED9) * 0x8088405) & 0xFFFF);
        string checksum = seqNumber.ToString("X",inv).ToUpperInvariant();
        if (checksum != val.Substring(11, 4)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT: Added Unchecked keyword: the overflow errors that would occur appear to be unimportant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool validateSequenceNumber(string val, int num)
{
    float seqNumber = (Int32)((Single.Parse(num) + 0xCED9) * 0x8088405) & 0xFFFF;
    string checksum = seqNumber.ToString("X").ToUpper();
    return (checksum != val.Substring(11, 4) ? false : true);
}
```